# Looking for a template or jquery plugin to mimic usatoday.com full page slider effect

Tags: jquery, slideshow

There is bunch of image sliders out there but I'm looking for something that USAtoday.com uses arrows on the side of the screen to go to previous or next page.  Does anyone know any scripts or templates that does the similar?

Thanks in advance